# Objeto instanciado não aparece em função

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, funções, eclipse, objetos

Olá, estou criando um projeto em Java usando o Eclipse com o windowbuilder. Dentro desse projeto possuo o JFrame com os objetos, jbuttons, jtextfields, jformattedtextfields, etc... Tenho todos esses objetos no meu projeto. Ocorre que, quando eu tento criar uma função no início do código para dar ações nesses objetos, esses objetos não aparecem nas funções. É como se eles não existissem. Não consigo criar funções, métodos, ações para esses objetos porque não aparecem nas funções. Alguém sabe porque isso acontece... ?

Aqui estão os objetos instanciados:

```
        JTextPane PEQuestion = new JTextPane();
        PEQuestion.setText("1) Ao fazer compras no supermercado:");
        PEQuestion.setBounds(10, 280, 599, 48);
        Question.add(PEQuestion);

JTextPane peTextA = new JTextPane();
        peTextA.setText("A) Compro tudo que tenho vontade, sem prestar aten\u00E7\u00E3o no pre\u00E7o, na marca ou na embalagem;");
        peTextA.setBounds(34, 339, 540, 48);
        Question.add(peTextA);
        
        JTextPane peTextB = new JTextPane();
        peTextB.setText("B) Uso apenas o pre\u00E7o como crit\u00E9rio de escolha;");
        peTextB.setBounds(34, 395, 540, 48);
        Question.add(peTextB);

    JTextPane peTextC = new JTextPane();
    peTextC.setText("C) Presto aten\u00E7\u00E3o se os produtos de uma determinada marca s\u00E3o ligados a alguma empresa que n\u00E3o respeita o meio ambiente ou quest\u00F5es sociais;");
    peTextC.setBounds(34, 449, 540, 48);
    Question.add(peTextC);
    
    JTextPane peTextD = new JTextPane();
    peTextD.setText("D) Procuro considerar pre\u00E7o e qualidade, al\u00E9m de escolher produtos que venham em embalagens recicl\u00E1veis e que respeitem crit\u00E9rios ambientais e sociais.");
    peTextD.setBounds(34, 504, 540, 48);
    Question.add(peTextD);
```

E aqui as funções que tento criar com os objetos (no início da classe), e que não identificam os objetos:

```
public void mudarTexto()

{
    PEQuestion.setText("2) Entre os alimentos que normalmente você consome, que quantidade é pré-preparada, embalada ou importada?");
    peTextA.setText("A) Quase todos;");
    peTextB.setText("B) Metade;");
    peTextC.setText("C) Um quarto;");
    peTextD.setText("D) Muito poucos. A maior parte dos alimentos que consumo não é pré-preparada nem embalada, tem origem orgânica e é produzida na região onde vivo.");
    PEImg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(mainView.class.getResource("/peImages/02.png")));
}
```

O erro que aparece é:

> PEQuestion cannot be resolved
>
> peTextA cannot be resolved
>
> peTextB cannot be resolved
>
> peTextC cannot be resolved
>
> peTextD cannot be resolved

Obrigado.

Comment: Eles só existem no escopo em que são instanciados, correto?

Comment: Por que não declarar os controles em um escopo mais amplo, como o da classe? `class MinhaJanela extends JPanel { private JTextPane PEQuestion; /* mais abaixo */ public void metodoQueEuQueroTanto() { PEQuestion = new JTextPane(); } /* mais abaixo */ public void metodoQueEuQueroMais() { PEQuestion.setText("minha questão"); } }`

Comment: Os objetos estão dentro do método construtor e as funções antes do método construtor.

Comment: Não entendi. Como assim declarar em um escopo mais amplo?

Comment: O escopo de um bloco if é o próprio bloco if. O escopo de um método é o próprio método, inclusive os vários blocos ifs que porventura existam dentro dele. O escopo da classe são todos os métodos dentro da classe, e todos os blocos ifs de todos os métodos.

Answer (score 1):

Você está com um problema de escopo. Quando você declara ***novas*** variáveis em um método, elas só pertencem aquele método. Se você quiser que uma variável seja acessada por todos os métodos de uma classe, você tem que declarar (se quiser também pode inicializar) ela no corpo da classe, fora dos métodos. No seu caso, você deve estar querendo algo desse tipo:

```
public class MinhaClasse {

    // Variáveis declaradas no escopo da classe podem 
    // ser acessadas em qualquer método
    JTextPane peQuestion = new JTextPane(); //Nome de variável deve ser CamelCase
    JTextPane peTextA = new JTextPane();
    JTextPane peTextB = new JTextPane();
    JTextPane peTextC = new JTextPane();
    JTextPane peTextD = new JTextPane();

    public MinhaClasse() {

        // As variáveis usadas aqui são as que pertencem a classe
        peQuestion.setText("1) Ao fazer compras no supermercado:");
        peQuestion.setBounds(10, 280, 599, 48); Question.add(peQuestion);

        peTextA.setText("A) Compro tudo que tenho vontade, sem prestar aten\u00E7\u00E3o no pre\u00E7o, na marca ou na embalagem;");
        peTextA.setBounds(34, 339, 540, 48); Question.add(peTextA);

        peTextB.setText("B) Uso apenas o pre\u00E7o como crit\u00E9rio de escolha;");
        peTextB.setBounds(34, 395, 540, 48); Question.add(peTextB);

        peTextC.setText("C) Presto aten\u00E7\u00E3o se os produtos de uma determinada marca s\u00E3o ligados a alguma empresa que n\u00E3o respeita o meio ambiente ou quest\u00F5es sociais;");
        peTextC.setBounds(34, 449, 540, 48); Question.add(peTextC);

        peTextD.setText("D) Procuro considerar pre\u00E7o e qualidade, al\u00E9m de escolher produtos que venham em embalagens recicl\u00E1veis e que respeitem crit\u00E9rios ambientais e sociais.");
        peTextD.setBounds(34, 504, 540, 48);
        Question.add(peTextD);
    }

    public void mudarTexto() {

        // As variáveis usadas aqui são as que pertencem a classe
        peQuestion.setText("2) Entre os alimentos que normalmente você consome, que quantidade é pré-preparada, embalada ou importada?");
        peTextA.setText("A) Quase todos;");
        peTextB.setText("B) Metade;");
        peTextC.setText("C) Um quarto;");
        peTextD.setText("D) Muito poucos. A maior parte dos alimentos que consumo não é pré-preparada nem embalada, tem origem orgânica e é produzida na região onde vivo.");
        PEImg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(mainView.class.getResource("/peImages/02.png")));
    }

    //Exemplo de acesso de variáveis em determinados escopos
    public void outroEscopo() {

         JTextPane peTextA = new JTextPane();
         peTextA.setText("Eu pertenço APENAS ao escopo desse método");

         // Se você tiver em um método alguma variável com o mesmo
         // nome de alguma variável que pertença ao escopo da classe
         // basta usar o THIS para acessar a variável da classe

         this.peTextA.setText("Eu pertenço ao escopo da classe");
    }
}
```

**Obs.:** Fique de olho nas mensagens da IDE, pois a não ser que você não tenha nenhum linter configurado, a IDE sempre te avisa sobre esses tipos de problemas de escopo antes mesmo de compilar o código.

Answer (score 0):

Se você declarar

```
class MinhaClasse
{
    public void MinhaOperacao(int meuParametro)
    {
        if (meuParametro % 2 == 0)
        {
            JTextPane PEQuestion = new JTextPane();
        }

        PEQuestion.setText("teste 1");
    }
}
```

ele vai dar o mesmo erro. Por quê? Porque `PEQuestion` não foi declarado no escopo da linha `PEQuestion.setText("teste 1");`.

O que fazer?

Se você deseja usar `PEQuestion` em toda a classe, basta declará-la no escopo da classe,

```
class MinhaClasse
{
    private JTextPane PEQuestion;

    public MinhaClasse()
    {
        PEQuestion = new JTextPane();
    }

    public void MinhaOperacao(int meuParametro)
    {
        if (meuParametro % 2 == 0)
        {
            PEQuestion.setText("teste 2");
        }
    }
}
```